# PHP PDO-MySQL prepared statement with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I know you can't use the " character, tried ` instead and that didn't work, any ideas?

```
$sql = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO testDB VALUES(`$title`,`$bodytext`,`$created`)');
```

Comment: backticks are for escaping reserved words. You want regular `'` single quotes. And since you're using prepared statements, you shouldn't be inserting values like that directly anyways. All the prepared statements in the world won't save you from SQL injection attacks if you're not using them properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO testDB VALUES(?, ?, ?)');
$sql->execute(array($title, $bodytext, $created));
```

What I did was removing the variables from the SQl query and replaced them with `?` as placeholder. You only bind values to the statement at execution time.

The way you tried to do it was no different from using regular SQL queries.

Comment: Works but my web vulnerability scanner can still hack the site :(

Comment: Nvm, turned out the code only displayed 3 rows at a time, scanner didn't actually overwrite old data so everything is fine. Thanks for your help!